# How to center align text in MARKDOWN language?

Tags: markdown, flutter-textinputfield

I want to align my heading

### Heading

at center in my blogs.
I am using flutter by the way to display markdown

I found a way by using div containers which is somewhat similar to html but if anyone seeing this question has better idea please contribute.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

[Markdown is concerned with *content*, not presentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

> The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

You aren't giving us much detail about how you are using Flutter to display your content, but the solution won't be a pure Markdown one. A common approach when rendering to HTML is to modify the stylesheet being used (because *CSS* is about presentation).